# tkinter program displays the location of the mouse pointer on the canvas when the mouse is clicked

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Trying to get the coordinates of the mouse pointer to display on the canvas where the mouse is.  Here is the code.  I can get text to display just cannot find the trick to display the coordinates of the mouse itself.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *                
width = 250
height = 250
class MainGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk() 
        window.title("Display Cursor Position")
        self.canvas = Canvas(window, bg = "white", width = width, height = height)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.processMouseEvent)
        self.canvas.focus_set()
        window.mainloop()
    def processMouseEvent(self, event):
        self.canvas.create_text(event.x, event.y, text = "event.x, event.y")
        #self.canvas.insert(cursorPoint)
MainGUI()
```

Answer (score 3):

In this line

```
self.canvas.create_text(event.x, event.y, text = "event.x, event.y")
```

the first two arguments tells you where the text is positioned in the canvas. As you want to insert the coordinates of the mouse, you have to convert event.x and event.y into strings (they are ints). So:

```
def processMouseEvent(self, event):
    mouse_coordinates= str(event.x) + ", " + str(event.y)
    self.canvas.create_text(event.x, event.y, text = mouse_coordinates)
```

Comment: Thanks much for your help.  I tried going down that path earlier, spending probably half a day trying to tie the x,y to a variable of some kind or another, but was never able to put it together in a way that didn't throw an exception at me.  Now I know why!  Thanks again!